# How to always read scale weight from usb using serial ports

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb

I am trying to read the weight from a scale (model Cas PRII). I followed various links on how to do this with serial ports, also followed the documentation but [SerialDataReceivedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) fires only when I add something to the scale.

- So, I add object A and it fires with 2 kg for example.
- I remove object A, nothing happens but I would like to have an event that now the scale is zero.
- If I add again object A, I get the event again.
- Now I add object B over A, but nothing happens. I would have expected to get another event for this.
- Also, if the weight is very low, like 0.005 kg, it never fires.

The version of the code below, fires only if I put something on the scale. Example

- I put A on scale, data receiver get called
- remove A, put another object B, data receiver get's called
- if I keep B, and add A on top, nothing happens

```
 // setup serial port
 public SerialPort comport = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
 comport.BaudRate = 9600; 
 comport.Parity = Parity.None;
 comport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
 comport.DataBits = 8; 
 comport.Handshake = Handshake.None
 comport.PortName = "COM3";//comprt; //"COM3";
 comport.DtrEnable = true;
 comport.RtsEnable = true;

 comport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

 OpenPort(comport);


 // event handler
 public void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
   SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
   string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
   DisplayToUI(indata);     
 }
```

I tried creating a button and create a new serial port every time I click the button, and reading the existing data. But it is always 0, even though there is weight on the scale.

I would like to know, if there is a way I can ask the scale at any point what weight is showing, like reading its memory at that moment?
Do you think this is a configuration problem? Maybe the scale options can be changed so it fires an event every time?

```
  public void DisplayToUI(string displayData)
    {
        if (displayData == string.Empty)
        {
            displayData = " 0.00\r  0.000kg\r  0 / kg  \r";

        }
        string[] response = displayData.Split('\r');

        getMedian(response);
       
    }
```

Comment: Use another serial terminal program (PuTTY or HTerm or Realterm or many other choices) to look at the data coming from the scale and see whether the problem is your program or what the scale is sending.  If the scale isn't sending decreases, call the manufacturer, how to do that is not a programming question.

Comment: Can we see your `DisplayToUI` code?

Comment: @Baddack yes i can, but only when the events get called. so, if i out  A the first time, i see 2 kg. i take off A, there is still 2 kg on my desktop as no event was send. Then i put B, it changes to 2,8 kg. so every time  i add smth new  after removing the first one it works..

Comment: @BenVoigt  I will try thank you. I was wondering though if there is any other way to go and read directly  to the scale memory , as the sale shows the right number in it's small screen?

Comment: @BenVoigt So i tried with putty and it behaves the same as my code.

Comment: @BenVoigt It behaves the same as my code in Putty with the difference that it reads even the low weight.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to read the scales memory, that is why they have given you serial communication.  Do you have a link to the scale you bought so I can look at it's user manual and see its serial communication specification?

Comment: @Baddack  http://www.globalcas.com/main/main.php